# Is there any software available to control a Windows 7 PC with a Kinect?

Tags: windows-7, kinect

Now that the SDK has been out for a bit, is there any software available to control a Windows 7 PC with a Kinect?  I'd like to get rid of my mouse attached to my media center PC.  This is mainly to be used with Windows Media Center.

I've seen some videos and demos, but can't seem to find anything to download.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lfso7_i9Ko8  Cool in theory, but worthless IRL.  Stick with a bluetooth mouse or get one of those remote-control dealies with a trackball.

Comment: I disagree.  Using the kinect with xbox media center and netflix is a great interface, and is where interfaces are headed.

Comment: http://codelaboratories.com/nui/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working on a solution for Windows Media Center. Check out [Kinect for Media Center](http://www.bradmauk.me/TheMediaCenterProject).